# Inline requests inside parse function in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to obtain the text of `link.url` in this case. So `links` contain a set of urls and in each iteration, attach the text inside from `link.url`. For this, scrapy needs to visit `link.url`. I do that by sending a request and then the callback function is supposed to extract the text. But in the output file, I see that the `text` field contains `links.url` and not the text from `links.url`.
Briefly, I want something like `fetch` function from scrapy shell which returns everything inside `response` object but in python. This is what I'm trying to do inside the code below:

```
class TravelSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "travel"
    allowed_domains = allowed_domains
    start_urls = urls

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
        #  'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 5
    }

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_links=process_links)]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)

        for link in links:
            is_allowed = False
            for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
                if allowed_domain in link.url:
                    is_allowed = True

            if is_allowed:
                item = ScraperItem()
                item['url_from'] = response.url
                item['url_to'] = link.url
                request = scrapy.Request(link.url, callback=self.parse_single, meta={'item': item}, dont_filter=True)
                #  items.append(req.meta['item'])
                return request

    def parse_single(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        para_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//p//text()').extract())
        span_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//span//text()').extract())
        div_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//div/text()').extract())
        item['text'] = clean_text(para_text + ' ' + span_text + ' ' + div_text)
        return item
```

I even tried this [library](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests) but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `meta` solution is a good one [(or even better using `cb_kwargs`)](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) but if I understand your question correctly you don't need to do this.

Every `response` has [its `request`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?#scrapy.http.Response.request) as an attribute. You an access the `headers` of the request to get the `Referer` i.e. the url from which the request was made. You can do this by

```py
response.request.headers.get("referer")
```

this returns bytes, so you can decode it (if it is not `None`) with e.g.

```py
from_url = response.request.headers.get("referer").decode("utf-8")
```

Because `scrapy` does this in its logging there is actually a function to get this string directly

```py
from scrapy.utils.request import referer_str
from_url = referer_str(response.request)
```

so you can put this directly into your `parse_single` function to get all the information you need together

```py
def parse_single(self, response):
    item = ScraperItem()
    item['url_from'] = referer_str(response.request)
    item['url_to'] = response.url
    
    para_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//p//text()').extract())
    span_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//span//text()').extract())
    div_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//div/text()').extract())
    combined_text = clean_text(para_text + ' ' + span_text + ' ' + div_text)
    item['text'] =  combined_text
    yield item
```

Comment: How should the `parse` function look like if everything is happening inside `parse_single` ?

Comment: Depends what you want to do, but it looks like you could probably just delete `parse` and change the `callback` of your `Rule` to `parse_single`. The `CrawlSpider` should be doing the request filtering anyway

Comment: I did that exactly but didn't work, output is empty. I am not sure how it is supposed to work. I'd expect the solution above to work but it also doesnt. How am I sending requests to `links.url` in your solution ? I've updated the description with the latest code I'm trying.

Comment: It’s hard to tell what’s wrong without the url of the site you are trying to scrape. I’d think you just let the spider handle the requests and you’d just have rules and `parse_single`

Comment: I'm trying to scrape tripadvisor. You can see any link and test if possible.

Comment: You aren't returnng are you? You should be yielding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230561/discussion-between-tomjn-and-kl-divergence).

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case of using meta on request. What you want to do is below

1. Generate the item without the text
2. Pass the item as a meta for request url for which text needs to be collected
3. Yield the item once the text is available

Not tested but something on below lines should help you

```py
class TravelSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "travel"
    allowed_domains = allowed_domains
    start_urls = urls

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 5,
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 1,
        #  'CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT': 5
    }

    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_links=process_links)]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        links = LinkExtractor(canonicalize=True, unique=True).extract_links(response)

        for link in links:
            is_allowed = False
            for allowed_domain in self.allowed_domains:
                if allowed_domain in link.url:
                    is_allowed = True

            if is_allowed:
                item = ScraperItem()
                item['url_from'] = response.url
                item['url_to'] = link.url
                yield scrapy.Request(link.url , self.parse_single, meta={'item': item}, dont_filter=True)

    def parse_single(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        para_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//p//text()').extract())
        span_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//span//text()').extract())
        div_text = ''.join(response.xpath('//div/text()').extract())
        combined_text = clean_text(para_text + ' ' + span_text + ' ' + div_text)
        item['text'] = combined_text
        return item
```

Comment: I tried it, I get crawled n pages in m seconds, scraped 0 pages, in the output file, its empty.

Comment: I modified the description with the code I tried based on your suggestion. I tried your code with yield.

Comment: I'm not getting any exception. It just keeps on crawling without appending anything to output file.

Comment: Is the `parse_single` being called at all or not? It should be some minor issue that you will have to debug

Comment: I am also suspecting that. Tried to print outputs, doesn't get shown, but why does it not get called ? We are explicitly adding it as callback.